# Python tkinter.ttk combobox throws exception on quit

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter, ttk

In my Python 3.3 code I use some comboboxes from the ttk library, and they function fine, but if I use any of them, I got an exception when I close the window with the X button. This is an example:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Label,Button
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

def cbox_do(event):
    'Used for cbox.'
    clabel.config(text=cbox.get())

a = Tk()
cbox = Combobox(a, value=('Luke','Biggs','Wedge'), takefocus=0)
cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", cbox_do)
cbox.pack()
clabel = Label(a)
clabel.pack()
a.mainloop()
```

If you close it without selecting a value, everithing is fine, but try to close it after a value was selected, it exits but prints the following error into the python command line:

```
can't invoke "winfo" command:  application has been destroyed
    while executing
"winfo exists $w"
    (procedure "ttk::entry::AutoScroll" line 3)
    invoked from within
"ttk::entry::AutoScroll .41024560"
    (in namespace inscope "::" script line 1)
    invoked from within
"::namespace inscope :: {ttk::entry::AutoScroll .41024560}"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 $Repeat(script)"
    (procedure "ttk::Repeat" line 3)
    invoked from within
"ttk::Repeat"
    ("after" script)
```

How could I fix it? I would be grateful for any help you could provide.

Update 1:
My Python version is v3.3, I use the bundled Tcl/Tk and Tkinter. I tried both the x86 and x64 versions.

Update 2:
The exception is thrown only if I run my script from command line. It wont show up in Idle.

Comment: Your code does work for me. I think the problem is the Tkinter version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My Tcl/Tk version is 8.5 and ttk is v0.3.1. It was part of Python v3.3 when I installed it. I found an update and soon I will write my experiences after I tried it.

Comment: I haven't managed to update Tkinter. Tcl/Tk v8.6 is exsits [link](http://www.tcl.tk/) but I could not integrate it to Python. May I ask which Tkinter and Python version you have used? I would like to try the script on that version.

Comment: Mine is also 8.5 with ttk 0.3.1. I've tried your code with Python 2.7.3 (changing the imports) and with Python 3.0.1, and I haven't had any problem. I hope someone else can come out with the issue.

Comment: I tried v3.0.1. ttk was mising from Tkinter.I tested my script in IDLE under v3.3. It seems fine (no exception). But I always got the exception in command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the Tcl/Tk binding code used in ttk.

The problem is hinted at by a comment in tcl/tk8.5/ttk/entry.tcl file in a typical python Tkinter installation:

```
## AutoScroll
#   Called repeatedly when the mouse is outside an entry window
#   with Button 1 down.  Scroll the window left or right,
#   depending on where the mouse is, and extend the selection
#   according to the current selection mode.
#
# TODO: AutoScroll should repeat faster (50ms) than normal autorepeat.
# TODO: Need a way for Repeat scripts to cancel themselves.
```

Basically a deferred call with `after` isn't canceled and cannot complete anymore after the last window gets closed and Tk is finalized, because the procedure/function 'winfo' no longer exists. When you run IDLE, there still is a window, so Tk does not get finalized and the error does not show up.

You can fix this with a binding on the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` message, which stops the repeat timer. The code for that would be (in Tcl/Tk):

```
proc shutdown_ttk_repeat {args} {
    ::ttk::CancelRepeat
}
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW shutdown_ttk_repeat
```

For Tkinter it should work in a similar way:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Label,Button
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

def cbox_do(event):
    'Used for cbox.'
    clabel.config(text=cbox.get())

a = Tk()
cbox = Combobox(a, value=('Luke','Biggs','Wedge'), takefocus=0)
cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", cbox_do)
cbox.pack()
clabel = Label(a)
clabel.pack()

def shutdown_ttk_repeat():
    a.eval('::ttk::CancelRepeat')
    a.destroy()

a.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", shutdown_ttk_repeat)
a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Now I see what is problem. I tried the Tkinter solution, but now it prints the following exception and doesn't close the window:
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call
    __
        return self.func(*args)
    TypeError: shutdown_ttk_repeat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
What am I doing wrong? I'm new in python so sorry for being a noob.

Comment: ah, my fault, just use: `def shutdown_ttk_repeat()` without any parameters, i assumed it would get args like the Tcl version does.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. :) No exceptions this time, but the close button stopped working. I added `an a.destroy()` line after `a.eval('::ttk::CancelRepeat')`, and now it is working flawlessly. I'm very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem recently. The error message is exactly the same. 
I solved that by adding a a.quit() in an Exit method. (before that there was only a.destroy() in this method)
Maybe you have already solved this question. But schlenk's answer doesn't work well on me. So I hope my answer can give another clue to such question

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem but I was able to solve it by using tk.Toplevel(),try replacing
`a=Tk()`
with
`a=Toplevel()`
I know this is late but,I was able to solve this issue in mycase

Comment: You would never solve this questions by your suggested changes. It has quite simply nothing to do with Toplevel vs Tk

Comment: @Thingamabobs that's the reason why I mentioned in my case